# Unable to use user data directory msedge

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge, user-data

I have a problem here I'm trying to run edge (from msedge-selenium-tools) and it doesn't open the default profile here's the code:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
edgeoptions = EdgeOptions()
edgeoptions.add_argument(R"user-data-dir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data")
driver = Edge("msedgedriver.exe",options=edgeoptions)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

it doesn't load the profile and yes is there an any way to get rid of edge being pinned to taskbar?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I didn't notice the traceback whole time:

```
[3972:7544:0727/224625.954:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:46:25.954] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[3972:7544:0727/224625.961:ERROR:profile_manager.cc(1058)] Cannot create profile at path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default
[3972:7544:0727/224625.961:ERROR:profile_manager.cc(2038)] Cannot create profile at path C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default
[3972:7544:0727/224626.122:ERROR:secondary_tile_client.cc(219)] OnSecondaryTileManagerDisconnected. Sending error response to callbacks
[3972:7544:0727/224633.600:ERROR:CONSOLE(1355)] "Uncaught (in promise) undefined", source: https://assets.msn.com/bundles/v1/edgeChromium/latest/common.2c045991234e451853e9.js (1355)
```

Comment: Right click on the taskbar icon.  There's a menu entry for "Unpin from taskbar".

Comment: @TimRoberts yea I know about that but to start it without pinning I don't know

Comment: You can put an icon on the desktop.  You can start it from the Start Menu.  You can run "https://www.google.com" from the Start Menu or from a command line.

Comment: @TimRoberts you can check it again didn't see the traceback whole time

Comment: Are you running this as a different user, or in a Windows service?

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry I don't think I understood

Comment: What I mean is that `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local` is only accessible by the user called `User`.  If you are running this on a different system, or as a "scheduled task" that runs as the system user, then you won't have permission.  How are you running this?

Comment: @TimRoberts It is accessed by my profile (User) I tried this on chrome webdriver and it worked but edge doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved my problem

Thank you all
Edit:
I used

```
edgeoptions.use_chromium = True
```